# How can I use a void pointer as a parameter, of a function, in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I use a void pointer as a parameter, of a function, in C#?

Comment: Why do you want to? P/Invoke? Provide more detail please

Comment: i am declaring a function of a class in c++ which contain 2 parameters.1st parameter is void pointer and other one is DWORD.i am converting this function in C#.i am not getting how i should convert void pointer in C#

Answer (score 2):

Provided your C function looks like this:

```
int Foo(void* p, DWORD dwVal);
```

and you just rewriting it in C# then for most of the time all you need is something like this:

```
int Foo(object obj, uint val);
```

But if you are doing Interops then use P/Invoke as suggested above. A good place to start in this case is http://www.pinvoke.net/